# isEmpty() in a Circular Queue without count approach/

Tags: java

I've understood the whole code with no problem when reading the book, but I don't understand a certain condition in a method.

Background : The goal is to implement a Queue using "arrays" without using a count variable to keep track of items, instead you have the size n set to n+1, and relying on front and rear to get your values.

```
public boolean isEmpty() // true if queue is empty {
     return ( rear+1==front || (front+maxSize-1==rear) );
}
```

I tried my best to trace the second condition in the return statement, but I can't get it. ( front+maxSize-1==rear)

Can someone please provide some help?

Comment: what are front and rear? I'm assuming they are Integers.

Comment: What is the value of maxSize?

Comment: Maxsize = the size of the Queue intended by the user +1.

Comment: I can't wrap my head around this one either. I'm not sure why there are two conditions for it anyways. Is there ever a situation where `rear + 1 == front` is false, but the queue is empty?

Comment: So it is kind of fancy way of saying `(front == 0 && rear == maxsize-1)`

Comment: @eckes exactly. See the answer below

Comment: I typically tend to prefer the expressions which are less optimized, more explicite (and have less risk of being ambigous).

Answer (score 1):

Your internal `array` size is `maxSize`.
Imagine situation when your queue holds one element and `front` and `rear` both point to last slot of array. 
I.e.

```
front == rear == maxSize - 1;
```

When you pop() this last element, your `front` will "circularly" move to index 0, and your queue should become empty.

But since your `rear` does not move on pop() it will still be `maxSize - 1`.

The latter condition `front+maxSize-1==rear` catches exactly this particular situation (which does not match the first condition since `front` is smaller than `rear` in that case)

***edit***
To combine both your conditions in one you could write :

```
// true if rear is one "step" behind front
public boolean isEmpty() {
     return (rear + 1) % maxSize == front; // based on suggestion of @eckes
}
```

Hope that is clear.

Comment: ((rear + 1) % maxSize == front)

Comment: @eckes yep, looks a bit better. Feel free to edit the answer if you like.

Comment: In the book, it's written that if rear reaches max size-1, it will return to index 0. ( or -1, then we use array[++index] in the insert operation, while Front will only reset to zero if it reaches maxsize, that's what confuses me, because within these , it will never reach that condition.

Comment: Let's say your queue is empty and `front == maxSize - 1` and `rear == maxSize - 2`; What happens when you push() one element ? What will `front` and `rear` become ?